# Weird blocks when adding Elements to MonoTouch Dialog RootElement after it is shown

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In an app I am building I use the following pattern: If the user clicks on a hierarchical navigation element I open the next `UIViewController` immediately, and it takes care about loading its data itself and shows a loading spinner if it is going over the network.

Now most list views are created using `MonoTouch`. On one `DialogViewController` I have an issue with adding many element to the views RootElement after the screen has already been show.

At first the `StringElements` appear fine on screen, but if you scroll quickly up and down the text on each line becomes a block:

[image: screenshot of the issue at hand]

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
        var root = new RootElement("Root");
        var dvc = new DialogViewController(root) { AutoHideSearch = true, EnableSearch = true };

        nav.PushViewController(dvc, true);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                var sec = new Section();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var el = new StyledStringElement("Test", "Test", UITableViewCellStyle.Value1);
                    sec.Add(el);
                }

                root.Add(sec);
            });
        });
```

Interestingly only the string on the left looks like a block, while the one on the right is fine. On a side note, in their MWC (demo) app, [Xamarin created a new RootElement to repopulate the twitter list as well](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/master/MWC/MWC.iOS/Screens/iPhone/Twitter/TwitterScreen.cs#L103).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be a reload of the data source called on the main thread to correctly render the new values:

```
var dvc = new DialogViewController(new RootElement(""));
_root = new UINavigationController();
_root.PushViewController(dvc, true);
_window.RootViewController = _root;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    var section = new Section("");
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 100)) {
            section.Add(new StyledStringElement(i.ToString(), "cell", UITableViewCellStyle.Value1));
        }

    dvc.Root.Add(section);
    BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        dvc.ReloadData();
    });
});
```

Comment: But how come it works at first, and breaks after scrolling down and up again?

Comment: Sorry it seems my initial hypothesis was wrong. I'm adjusting the answer.

Comment: Adding `dvc.ReloadData();` indeed fixes the behavior. But from my limited understanding this is a bug I should file. Please vote on the question since you found it worthwhile to answer ;-) I will wait with the "accept" until I hear back from the bug report.

Comment: had the problem .. i decided to create an element by my self to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly have the same issue when I'm rendering dynamically the element in an BeginInvokeOnMainThread statement
If I do load my elements in the constructor, the UI is blocked but the elements will render well.

and thanks for the tip dvc.ReloadData will work as well for me