# MonoTouch: MonoTouch.Dialog Rendering titles

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In the below image you can see that in a StyleStringElement in a list, when scrolled quickly the title renders black. If I rotate the ipad the list re-renders and is fine.

Is there a work around?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's the issue but it's been reported previously: [Weird blocks when adding Elements to MonoTouch Dialog RootElement after it is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456650/weird-blocks-when-adding-elements-to-monotouch-dialog-rootelement-after-it-is-sh)

That might give you a workaround but it would be nice if you could fill a bug report (and a test case) on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com so this can be properly fixed in future releases.

Comment: I think it's probably a bug so will mark this question as closed and will submit a bug request.